# How do I build this array to output?

Tags: php

I have the following function which fetches some data from a MySQL table:

```
function readQuestion ($quizType, $questionId) {
  $data = array();
  $query = $this->dbConnection->query("SELECT * FROM $quizType WHERE id = $questionId");
  foreach ($query as $row) {
    var_dump($row);
  };
  echo $data
}
```

How can I push all the returned data into an array, where each member is indexed by a number?

Do I need to use echo or return at the end? They seem to have the same effect.

EDIT: Is this the correct way of returning results of the query? I am passing it to the front-end.

```
 $questionData = $controller->readQuestion($quizType, $questionId);
 return $questionData;
```

Comment: just assign it in your array

Comment: You can't use `echo` on an Array. If you're using MySQLi to make your connection, please use prepared statements because if that `$questionId` or `$quizType` is user inputted data then you're in for a bad time.

Comment: I am using PDO.

Answer (score 0):

In general your function must looks like:

```
function readQuestion ($quizType, $questionId) {
  $data = array();
  $query = $this->dbConnection->query("SELECT * FROM $quizType WHERE id = $questionId");
  return $query; 
}
```

But, you have to look what is inside `$query` variable. If it is array - just return this array, if not - maybe it is some iterator, hence you have to check it and try to find method like `toArray` or something like that... Otherwise, you have to do something like:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($query as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
};
return $data;
```

Now you can use this function like:

```
var_dump(readQuestion($quizType, $questionId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look up [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) on how to secure your data.

Anyway, as I said in the comment you cannot use `echo` on an Array. And you can't do anything with the output of `var_dump`.

Change `var_dump($row);` for `$data[] = $row;`

and change `echo $data;` for `return $data;`

Comment: I edited the question, can you check? Front-end is returning nothing.

Answer (score -1):

```
function readQuestion ($quizType, $questionId) {
  $data = array();
  $query = $this->dbConnection->query("SELECT * FROM $quizType WHERE id = $questionId");
  foreach ($query as $row) {
   $data=$row;
  };
  return $result;
}
```